# Tor portable not running

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help

I have tor browser bundle portable on a usb stick. When I plug it in, and run tor, it works fine. However, I copied the files to a folder on the computer itself. When I run tor from there, it does not work. When I run it, it appears to do something, but then nothing happens. If I try to run it again, a dialog box saying that it is already running appears. I'm using windows 7. Do I have to run the portable version off a USB? If I don't want to have to plug in a USB, do I have to install tor on the machine, instead of just running the portable files?

Comment: The [answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/10507/88) is not correct. You can run Tor browser from your local hard drive (I do it myself with several Windows 7, 8, etc. boxes) as well as your USB stick.

Comment: Which directory on your Windows box do you use? Do you have write permissions to that directory? When you first copy it, please navigate to the `Data\Tor` subdirectory and see if Tor creates some files which start with `cached-`. How long did you wait from starting Tor browser until you tried to run it again?

Comment: I think "Tor Browser Bundle Portable" is it's own thing related to "portable apps", e.g. the version distributed **unsigned** over **http** here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/torbrowserportable/ ***Do not use this software, not an endorsement***

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's not just copy-and-run : it's tweaked a bit to be executed from a separate disk(=your flash drive). It's about path's and directories, so either use a USB stick, or use an image on temporary ramdrive

Comment: This explanation is wrong. One can run Tor browser from a stick as well as from an ordinary drive. Usually it doesn't matter if it is a Windows drive, a USB stick or something else.

Comment: @JensKubieziel *usually* it does not matter, but this glitch appears from time to time, this very glitch